# VBA para preencher célula vazia

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

bom dia,

Eu tenho uma planilha no excel que eu gostaria que quando eu imputasse uma data e apertasse o botão a macro colasse na próxima célula vazia na coluna A, 74 vezes. E que também copiasse duas colunas (B:C) com 74 valores cada e também jogasse na próxima vazia, vou mandar uma imagem pra resumir, eu não conheço nada de macro ou VBA, então precisaria mesmo da ajuda.

O circulo grande vermelho seriam os outros valores que ele teria que copiar e colar, esses não mudam então pode ser vamos supor B2:C75 pra jogar na próxima vazia também que seriam nas colunas B e C.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Bruno!
Segue o código que provavelmente comece a te ajudar, confesso que não ficou muito claro o que você pediu mas já serviu para iniciar as linhas abaixo. Espero que ajude que qualquer coisa só retornar nesse tópico. Atribua a macro **s_processo()** a um botão.

```
Option Explicit

Const total_de_linhas_preenchidas As Long = 74

Sub s_processo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    f_processo
    turno_horario
End Sub

Private Function f_processo()
    'executa somente na coluna A e em uma célula vazia.
    Dim celula_com_data As String
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim it As Long
    celula_com_data = "I1"
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 And ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
        linha = ActiveCell.Row
        For it = linha To (total_de_linhas_preenchidas + linha)
            Range("A" & it).Value = Range(celula_com_data).Value
        Next it
    End If
    celula_com_data = ""
    linha = 0
    it = 0
End Function

Private Function turno_horario()
    Dim faixa As String
    Dim celula_com_data As String
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim it As Long
    celula_com_data = "I1"
    faixa = "B2:C9"
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
        linha = ActiveCell.Row
        For it = linha To (total_de_linhas_preenchidas + linha) Step 10
            Range(faixa).Copy Destination:=Range("B" & it)
        Next it
    End If
    celula_com_data = ""
    linha = 0
    it = 0
    faixa = ""
End Function
```